# Can wfdb Matlab commands differ in Linux and OS X?

Tags: linux, macos, matlab

There is a common misunderstanding about restoring [wfdb](https://physionet.org/physiotools/matlab/wfdb-app-matlab/) in Matlab in different systems (mainly OS X), a bug since June/2015 - ticket [#106](https://github.com/ikarosilva/wfdb-app-toolbox/issues/106). Observation is that if the wfdb system breaks (etc just initiate function with wrong parameters), you cannot use the folder again where the system was initiated. 
I am thinking if the initiating commands of the system can be the source of the problem. 
Commands

```
[old_path]=which('rdsamp');if(~isempty(old_path)) rmpath(old_path(1:end-8)); end
wfdb_url='https://github.com/ikarosilva/wfdb-app-toolbox/raw/master/wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-10.zip';
[filestr,status] = urlwrite(wfdb_url,'wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-10.zip');%Octave users may have to download manually
unzip('wfdb-app-toolbox-0-9-10.zip');
cd mcode
addpath(pwd);savepath
```

These commands seem to be ok. 
However, I am not sure how OS X interact with them. 
I am discussing the issue also in Github [here](https://github.com/ikarosilva/wfdb-app-toolbox/issues/124) about *How to Delete wfdb Completely in a Directory?* and [here](https://github.com/ikarosilva/wfdb-app-toolbox/issues/123) about *How to Restore wfdb Without Changing Directory in OS X?*

---

How can the wfdb initiating commands differ between Linux and OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There are known bugs in the OS X package which do not have high priority for fixes. 
Use the package instead in Linux Debian.